# share video on google plus by open graph tags

Tags: google-plus

I want to share video on Google plus

I am using open graph tags

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="..." />
<meta property="og:url" content="..." />
<meta property="og:title" content="..." />
<meta property="og:type" content="..." />
<meta property="og:image" content="..." />
<meta property="og:video" content="..." />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="..." />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="..." />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="..." />
```

it does share as a link and not video.

Thumbnail displays but not embed video within it.

Answer (score 0):

Google+ only supports a [select few Open Graph tags](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/).

- og:title
- og:image
- og:description